STM32U5 bootloader xmodem hardfault errror
I am new to STM32 controllers and am working on flashing my application binary using Xmodem (bootloader) on the STM32U5A5VJ controller. The controller has secure and non-secure memory regions:
Secure region: 0x0C000000 to 0x0C3FFFFF
Non-secure region: 0x08000000 to 0x083FFFFF
In the secure region:
We have flashed the bootloader at 0x0C000000.
We have flashed the application at 0x0C008000. However, when the jump to the application is invoked, a hard fault occurs.
In the non-secure region:
We have flashed the bootloader at 0x08000000.
We have flashed the application at 0x08008000. However, we are unable to debug the code to determine the cause of the issue.
Could you please suggest a solution?

Hard fault is the result of a configurable fault being disabled.  Try enabling the others (bus fault etc) and then read the corresponding information registers (bus fault address register BFAR, etc)
